# Python: Interpolating grid of data with sets of coordinates and time

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have a 2d array of 8775x100 which has been flattened from a 8775x10x10 array, with the 10x10 being the grid and the 8775 being values at each timestep.

I have the coordinates for this grid in 1d arrays of x and y (making a 10x10 layout), along with another pair of 1d arrays of new coordinates (smaller grid, same 10x10 layout).

How can I interpolate the coarse data from the 8775x100 which is on the first set of coordinates to the other set?

I've tried griddata from scipy.interpolate but I can't quite get my head round where all the coordinates and the values go...

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to test on.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any purpose of reshaping your flattening your array; that would just throw away the information about how the grid is arrange in the x and y dimensions. You want this information.

Essentially, what you describe is just a regular grid, and scipy has a handy `RegularGridInterpolator` which we can easily construct

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate

# Starting data:
ts = np.linspace(0, 100.0, 8775)  # 0 to 100 seconds maybe
xs = np.linspace(0, 10.0, 10)     # 0 to 10 meters maybe
ys = np.linspace(0, 10.0, 10)     # 0 to 10 meters maybe
points = (ts, xs, ys)
values = np.random.rand(8775, 10, 10)  # array of data

interp = scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator(points, values)
```

You can test it out by evaluating it for any given time space coordinate.

```py
interp(t, x, y)
```

Constructing the entire data field across a new grid of data points requires us to use a `meshgrid` to construct each and every point and evaluate the interpolation at those.

```py
# Desired points for interpolated data (could be any range, and sizes)
new_ts = ts                           # maybe the same time steps
new_xs = np.linspace(0.5, 3.14, 10)   # maybe different range
new_ys = np.linspace(0, 10.0, 20)     # maybe different steps

new_points = np.meshgrid(new_ts, new_xs, new_ys, indexing='ij')
```

You can then interpolate them all (here I convert to a tuple so as to not make `interp` incorrectly try to use the input as one coordinate, which of course would fail).

```py
new_values = interp(tuple(new_points))
```